# Secret Token Not Taking After Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, secret-key

I've read the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161327/argumenterror-a-secret-is-required-to-generate-an-integrity-hash-for-cookie-ses) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110079/secret-token-error-in-rails-app) on issues with the `secret_token` / `secret_base_key` issue, but I haven't been able to fix my issue.

I have an rails application I just took over from someone else. I ran the server, and got the `Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of at least 30 characters"in config/initializers/secret_token.rb` error.

I updated my secret_token.rb to have a string. I tried a local environment variable, as well as both secret_token and _secret_base_key. I restarted the server each time.

Not sure how else I should troubleshoot the issue, as I keep getting the problem.

**What I've tried**

`::Application.config.secret_token = ENV['123124...30chars']`
`::Application.config.secret_token = '123124...30chars'`
`::Application.config.secret_key_base = '123124...30chars'`

--update--
Ended up following the instructions here. The previous developer had it declared locally so I guess I had to define the variable in my `~/.bash_profile`